# Compare 2 Large Text Files return matches to output.txt

Tags: python, powershell

I've been trying for 2 days to find a way to compare 2 text files in Python or Powershell and write the lines that appear in both files to an output file.

Example:
Text1.txt
`bird human dog hotdog film`

Text2.txt
`human mercedes dog crown clown`

Output.txt:
`human dog`

I am a total beginner and hope you can help me.

In Powershell I find many Side Indicator examples but only with listing like:
`Text1 Text 2 bird <= human == mercedes =>`

so what is duplicated in which file. but with several thousand lines it takes too long. In Powershell I only find examples that show the differences in the output.txt.

Test in Powershell:

```
compare-object -PassThru (get-content File2.txt) (get-content File1.txt | Select-Object -Unique)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple yet efficient way to do it with [`File.ReadLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=net-7.0) and LINQ [`Intersect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-7.0):

```bash
[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Intersect(
    [System.IO.File]::ReadLines('absolute\path\to\file1.txt'),
    [System.IO.File]::ReadLines('absolute\path\to\file2.txt')) |
    Set-Content path\to\intersectedLines.txt
```

Worth noting that this intersection between lines is case-sensitive, if you need a case-insensitive comparison use the following:

```bash
[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Intersect(
    [System.IO.File]::ReadLines('absolute\path\to\file1.txt'),
    [System.IO.File]::ReadLines('absolute\path\to\file2.txt'),
    [System.StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) |
    Set-Content path\to\intersectedLines.txt
```